# History Table To From Dates trying to record specific column change

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

**Member Table:**

| ID | Date | DateCreated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 303896 | 2039-11-29 | 2017-11-03 21:47:51.000 |
| 303863 | 2044-03-02 | 2017-11-03 21:44:33.000 |
| 303843 | 2061-07-30 | 2017-11-03 21:43:39.000 |
| 303804 | 2025-10-08 | 2017-11-03 21:41:42.000 |
| 303795 | 2026-09-25 | 2017-11-03 21:41:18.000 |
| 303734 | 2035-02-21 | 2017-11-03 21:38:21.000 |
| 303701 | 2025-05-02 | 2017-11-03 21:36:44.000 |
| 303681 | 2065-12-13 | 2017-11-03 21:35:45.000 |
| 303398 | 2026-11-12 | 2017-11-03 21:21:39.000 |
| 303279 | 2028-02-14 | 2017-11-03 21:14:49.000 |
| 1 | 2054-10-15 | 2017-10-24 16:47:06.000 |

**Audit Member Table:**

| ID | Date | InsertedDateTime | DateCreated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2054-10-15 | 2023-10-26 02:04:03.167 | 2017-10-24 16:47:06.000 |
| 1 | NULL | 2023-10-06 01:51:29.740 | 2017-10-24 16:47:06.000 |
| 1 | NULL | 2023-02-21 02:44:33.050 | 2017-10-24 16:47:06.000 |
| 1 | NULL | 2023-02-12 03:00:17.440 | 2017-10-24 16:47:06.000 |
| 1 | NULL | 2021-04-24 07:44:12.060 | 2017-10-24 16:47:06.000 |
| 1 | NULL | 2020-11-30 02:38:42.583 | 2017-10-24 16:47:06.000 |
| 240125 | 2032-06-29 | 2023-10-12 01:50:52.803 | 2017-10-26 16:25:39.000 |
| 240125 | 2032-06-29 | 2023-02-12 03:00:17.440 | 2017-10-26 16:25:39.000 |
| 240125 | 2032-06-29 | 2021-05-20 01:36:25.320 | 2017-10-26 16:25:39.000 |
| 240125 | NULL | 2020-09-30 01:35:13.203 | 2017-10-26 16:25:39.000 |
| 240126 | 2047-01-02 | 2023-02-12 03:00:17.440 | 2017-10-26 17:03:18.000 |
| 245705 | 2035-08-28 | 2023-02-12 03:00:17.440 | 2017-10-27 10:56:08.000 |
| 245705 | 2065-08-28 | 2021-09-09 01:38:13.567 | 2017-10-27 10:56:08.000 |
| 245705 | 2035-08-28 | 2021-07-06 01:37:45.513 | 2017-10-27 10:56:08.000 |
| 245705 | 2038-08-28 | 2021-07-01 01:37:30.303 | 2017-10-27 10:56:08.000 |
| 245707 | 2049-03-13 | 2023-02-12 03:00:17.440 | 2017-10-27 11:33:38.000 |
| 251228 | 2047-01-01 | 2023-02-12 03:00:17.440 | 2017-10-27 21:08:16.000 |
| 251228 | NULL | 2021-07-15 08:32:57.513 | 2017-10-27 21:08:16.000 |

I have two tables a Cus table and an Audit Member table the audit_Member table consists of copies of previous records in the main Member Table to keep a history of records.  There is an inserted date in the Audit table to keep track of when a record was updated and inserted into the Audit table.

I am trying to find out when a certain column has been changed in this case (Retirement Date).

**Output Wanted**

| Date | DateFrom | ID | ToDate | FromDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2035-08-28 | 2035-08-28 | 245705 | 3000-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2023-02-12 03:00:17.440 |
| 2065-08-28 | 2035-08-28 | 245705 | 2021-09-09 01:38:13.567 | 2021-07-06 01:37:45.513 |
| 2035-08-28 | 2038-08-28 | 245705 | 2021-07-06 01:37:45.513 | 2021-07-01 01:37:30.303 |
| 2038-08-28 | NULL | 245705 | 2021-07-01 01:37:30.303 | 2017-10-27 10:56:08.000 |

My current code so far for current output:

I have only shown one Member record for reference

```
    WITH MemberAudit
AS (SELECT a.[RetirmentDate],
           a.ID,
           a.Date,
           [AuditRecord],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.ID ORDER BY a.ID, a.Date DESC) + 1 AS [ROWS] -- Create a sequential row number for each record
    FROM
    (
        SELECT c.RetirementDate [RetirmentDate],
               c.ID,
               GETDATE() [Date],
               'No' [AuditRecord]
        FROM Members c
        UNION
        SELECT ac.RetirementDate [RetirmentDate],
               ac.ID,
               ac.InsertedDateTime,
               'Yes' [AuditRecord]
        FROM AuditMembers ac
    ) a
      
    WHERE a.[RetirmentDate] IS NOT NULL),
     MemberAudit2
AS (SELECT a.[RetirmentDate],
           a.ID,
           a.Date,
           [AuditRecord],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.ID ORDER BY a.ID, a.Date DESC) AS [ROWS] -- Create a sequential row number for each record
    FROM
    (
        SELECT c.RetirementDate [RetirmentDate],
               c.ID,
               GETDATE() [Date],
               'No' [AuditRecord]
        FROM DwhV21.Members c
        UNION
        SELECT ac.RetirementDate [RetirmentDate],
               ac.ID,
               ac.InsertedDateTime,
               'Yes' [AuditRecord]
        FROM DwhV21.AuditMembers ac
    ) a
       
            ON a.ID = dc.Member_ID
    WHERE a.[RetirmentDate] IS NOT NULL),
     MemberAuditJoin
AS (SELECT ca.RetirmentDate,
           ca.ID,
           ca.Date,
           ca.AuditRecord,
           ca.ROWS,
           ca2.RetirmentDate [RetirmentDate1],
           ca2.ID [ID1],
           ca2.Date [Date1],
           ca2.AuditRecord [AuditRecord1],
           ca2.ROWS [ROWS1]
    FROM MemberAudit ca
        LEFT JOIN MemberAudit2 ca2
            ON ca2.ID = ca.ID
               AND ca2.ROWS = ca.ROWS),
     accountgrouping
AS (SELECT c.*,
           --c.RetirmentDate,
           --c.ID,
           CASE
               WHEN c.AuditRecord = 'No' THEN
                   '3000-01-01'
               WHEN c.AuditRecord = 'Yes' THEN
                   c.Date
           END [ToDate],
           CASE
               WHEN c.AuditRecord = 'No'
                    AND c.ID1 IS NOT NULL THEN
                   Date1
               WHEN c.AuditRecord = 'No'
                    AND c.ID1 IS NULL THEN
                   cus.DateCreated
               WHEN c.AuditRecord = 'Yes'
                    AND c.ID1 IS NULL THEN
                   cus.DateCreated
               WHEN c.AuditRecord = 'Yes'
                    AND c.ID1 IS NOT NULL THEN
                   c.Date1
           END [FromDate],
           CASE
               WHEN c.AuditRecord = 'No' THEN
                   'Yes'
               ELSE
                   'No'
           END [CurrentRecord],
           CASE
               WHEN c.RetirmentDate <> c.Date1 THEN
                   'Yes'
               ELSE
                   'No'
           END [RetirmentDateChange],
           CASE
               WHEN c.AuditRecord = 'Yes'
                    AND c.ID1 IS NULL THEN
                   'FirstAuditRecord'
           END [FirstAuditRecordMarker]
    FROM MemberAuditJoin c
        --WHERE c.RetirmentDate <> ISNULL(c.RetirmentDate1, '2099-01-01')
        JOIN DwhV21.Members cus
            ON c.ID = cus.ID)



SELECT RetirmentDate,
       ag.RetirmentDate1 [RetirmentDateFrom],
       ag.ID,
       ToDate [ToDate],
       ag.FromDate [FromDate],
       -- ag.CurrentRecord,
       ag.RetirmentDateChange,
       ag.FirstAuditRecordMarker,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ag.RetirmentDate,
                                       ag.ID,
                                       ag.RetirmentDate1
                          ORDER BY ToDate
                         ) AS lineNum
FROM accountgrouping ag

ORDER BY ag.ID,
         ToDate DESC;
```

Comment: @DaleK I have updated the fiddle and the output - To be honest I am just including a small subset of values I am working with trying to make sure I don't miss a scenario.  Struggling with it to be honest not sure if I am missing something obvious

Comment: This to first row of your desired output should have a "From Date" of "2065-08-28" not "2035-08-28"

Comment: dbfiddle.uk/AlXSqy-K I think this one is almost there but It is missing the current Value
Example the customer ID 245705 I would expect to see a toDate of either Null or a set future date as that is the current retirement date set

Comment: @DaleK I think you could be onto a winner here

Comment: Actually see my edited answer, all of the rows of other customers should also have had `3000-01-01` I believe, because none of them had more than a single un-duplicated row.

Comment: @Dalek I think is right for what is in the question.  I have just realized I missed one thing out there can be a client in the Customer Table without a corresponding record in the Audit Table the audit table is only updated if a current row exists. Currently these would be excluded.  But I think I should be able to cover them easy enough with an exists   statement or something like that and just add the records on to what you have produced.  Wont be quite as neat but should work.  

Or I will be able to figure out something with what you have provided.  Thanks

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This I believe creates the results you wish. Just a simple case of using [`LAG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to get the previous values to detect change and build the from/to date range.

```
with cte1 as (
  -- Lag relevant columns to detect changes
  select c.CustomerID, c.DateCreated
    , case when ac.CustomerID is not null then ac.[RetirementDate] else c.RetirementDate end RetirementDate
    , ac.[InsertedDateTime]
    , lag(ac.RetirementDate) over (partition by ac.CustomerId order by ac.InsertedDateTime asc) RetirementDateFrom
    , lag(ac.InsertedDateTime) over (partition by ac.CustomerId order by ac.InsertedDateTime asc) PreviousChangeDate
  from Customers c
  left join AuditCustomers ac on ac.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
), cte2 as (
  -- Remove sequential duplicate rows i.e. if the retirement age doesn't change from one row to the next
  select
    RetirementDate
    , RetirementDateFrom
    , CustomerId
    , coalesce(PreviousChangeDate,DateCreated) FromDate
    , InsertedDateTime
    , row_number() over (partition by cte1.CustomerId order by cte1.InsertedDateTime desc) rn
  from cte1
  where RetirementDate is not null
  and (RetirementDateFrom is null or RetirementDate <> RetirementDateFrom)
)
-- Transform a few values as required
select
  RetirementDate
  , RetirementDateFrom
  , CustomerId
  , FromDate
  , case when rn = 1 then '3000-01-01' else InsertedDateTime end ToDate
  , case when RetirementDate <> RetirementDateFrom then 1 else 0 end RetirementDateChange
  , case when RetirementDateFrom is null then 'FirstAuditRecord' else null end FirstAuditRecord
from cte2
order by customerid asc, InsertedDateTime desc;
```

| RetirementDate | RetirementDateFrom | CustomerId | FromDate | ToDate | RetirementDateChange | FirstAuditRecord |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2054-10-15 | *null* | 1 | 2023-10-06 01:51:29.740 | 3000-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 0 | FirstAuditRecord |
| 2054-10-15 | *null* | 2 | 2017-10-24 00:00:00.000 | 3000-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 0 | FirstAuditRecord |
| 2032-06-29 | *null* | 240125 | 2020-09-30 01:35:13.203 | 3000-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 0 | FirstAuditRecord |
| 2047-01-02 | *null* | 240126 | 2017-10-26 00:00:00.000 | 3000-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 0 | FirstAuditRecord |
| 2035-08-28 | 2065-08-28 | 245705 | 2021-09-09 01:38:13.567 | 3000-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 1 | *null* |
| 2065-08-28 | 2035-08-28 | 245705 | 2021-07-06 01:37:45.513 | 2021-09-09 01:38:13.567 | 1 | *null* |
| 2035-08-28 | 2038-08-28 | 245705 | 2021-07-01 01:37:30.303 | 2021-07-06 01:37:45.513 | 1 | *null* |
| 2038-08-28 | *null* | 245705 | 2017-10-27 00:00:00.000 | 2021-07-01 01:37:30.303 | 0 | FirstAuditRecord |
| 2049-03-13 | *null* | 245707 | 2017-10-27 00:00:00.000 | 3000-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 0 | FirstAuditRecord |
| 2047-01-01 | *null* | 251228 | 2021-07-15 08:32:57.513 | 3000-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 0 | FirstAuditRecord |
| 2071-10-01 | *null* | 266770 | 2022-11-17 02:50:49.087 | 3000-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 0 | FirstAuditRecord |
| 2044-06-02 | *null* | 297740 | 2021-02-22 02:38:36.873 | 3000-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 0 | FirstAuditRecord |
| 2037-01-07 | *null* | 299765 | 2020-06-20 01:34:39.790 | 3000-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 0 | FirstAuditRecord |
| 2053-09-06 | *null* | 303015 | 2019-11-08 02:32:52.680 | 3000-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 0 | FirstAuditRecord |
| 2034-01-25 | *null* | 303021 | 2017-11-03 00:00:00.000 | 3000-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 0 | FirstAuditRecord |
| 2025-10-08 | *null* | 303045 | 2017-11-03 00:00:00.000 | 3000-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 0 | FirstAuditRecord |
| 2028-10-30 | *null* | 303172 | 2020-03-29 01:32:11.793 | 3000-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 0 | FirstAuditRecord |
| 2028-02-14 | *null* | 303279 | 2023-02-02 02:54:20.713 | 3000-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 0 | FirstAuditRecord |
| 2022-11-12 | *null* | 303398 | 2021-12-23 02:38:29.560 | 3000-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 0 | FirstAuditRecord |
| 2065-12-13 | *null* | 303681 | 2020-07-04 01:39:00.880 | 3000-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 0 | FirstAuditRecord |
| 2019-02-21 | *null* | 303734 | 2017-11-03 00:00:00.000 | 3000-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 0 | FirstAuditRecord |
| 2026-09-25 | *null* | 303795 | 2021-06-28 01:36:26.573 | 3000-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 0 | FirstAuditRecord |
| 2025-10-08 | *null* | 303804 | 2022-09-06 01:45:54.723 | 3000-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 0 | FirstAuditRecord |
| 2061-07-30 | *null* | 303843 | 2017-11-03 00:00:00.000 | 3000-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 0 | FirstAuditRecord |
| 2044-03-02 | *null* | 303863 | 2021-01-25 02:39:37.847 | 3000-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 0 | FirstAuditRecord |
| 2039-11-29 | *null* | 303896 | 2020-12-11 06:48:24.517 | 3000-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 0 | FirstAuditRecord |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZJ4h09sS)

Comment: @Richard I've edited the answer to include the case where a customer (id=2) exists without any audit records. Its as simple as changing the join to a `left join` and then using a case expression to pull the customer record retirementdate in the case when no audit record exists.

Answer (score 1):

If you modify the audit table to contain previous data, it will be easy to get the result. in all case this is a query that give you what you want, I think it also give you a good performance.

```
CREATE TABLE #AuditCustomersTemp ( [CustomerID] int, [RetirementDate] date, [InsertedDateTime] datetime, [DateCreated] date )
insert into #AuditCustomersTemp 
select * from AuditCustomers 
union 
select  [CustomerID], [RetirementDate], N'2030-01-01' as [InsertedDateTime], [DateCreated] from Customers
order by [CustomerID], inserteddatetime 

create table #result (RetirmentDate date,   
RetirmentDateFrom date, CustomerID int, ToDate datetime,FromDate datetime)
While EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #AuditCustomersTemp)
Begin
    Declare @Id int;
    Declare @RetirmentDateFrom date = null;
    Declare @FromDate datetime;
    Select Top 1 @Id = CustomerID, @FromDate = DateCreated From #AuditCustomersTemp;
    While exists(select * from #AuditCustomersTemp where [CustomerID] = @ID )
    begin
        Declare @RetirmentDate date;
        Declare @ToDate datetime;
        Select Top 1 @RetirmentDate = RetirementDate  From #AuditCustomersTemp where CustomerID = @Id;
        While EXISTS(SELECT top 1 * FROM (select top 1 * from #AuditCustomersTemp) ACT where [CustomerID] = @id and (RetirementDate = @RetirmentDate
    or (RetirementDate is null and @RetirmentDate is null)))
        Begin
            select top 1  @ToDate = insertedDateTime From #AuditCustomersTemp where CustomerID = @Id;
            delete from #AuditCustomersTemp where CustomerID = @Id and  insertedDateTime = @ToDate;
        END
        insert into #result (RetirmentDate,RetirmentDateFrom ,  CustomerID ,ToDate ,FromDate ) values
        (@RetirmentDate, @RetirmentDateFrom, @Id,@ToDate,@FromDate)
        set @FromDate = @ToDate;
        set @RetirmentDateFrom = @RetirmentDate;
    End
End

select * from #result;
drop table #result;
drop table #AuditCustomersTemp;
```

Comment: @Richard I just adde a change, i didn't take into account that the RetirementDate can be null.

Comment: Loops should be avoided in SQL as they perform badly. You should be able to use set based operations.

Comment: @DaleK, for me yes, I did. We are 2000+ in the company, when I will tell my friends to down vote your answer this will not be the result. just an honest answer, no hate :).

Comment: bcs you did the same thing for me, for an answer that take an effort from me, a give a good result, and before doing this, i did a search regarding your recommendation abt the loop, I found nothing.